ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set')
I learn Express and JWT, and when I try to send access token via res.json i  get an error message
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const user = users.find((user) => user.name === req.body.username);
  if (user == null) {
    return res.status(400).send("Cannot find user");
  }
  try {
    if (await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)) {
      res.send("Success");
    } else {
      res.send("Not Allowed");
    }
  } catch {
    res.status(500).send();
  }
  const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
  res.json({ accessToken: accessToken });
});

What can I do to fix this?
I tried to set Content-Type header, but it isn't work or maybe I do something wrong because I only start study this

Send ends the request body

@DanielA.White how can I fix that then?

You can only send one response, so either res.send() or res.json(). You can't use both in the same request. That's why you usually return immediately when calling one of these function.

@Barmar, now i get a http-error 500

Check your server error log to find the reason for that.

@Barmar yes, I specified the wrong path. Thank you for your help!
